# Accuracy of Neural Networks incase of doing prediction of a continuious variable

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Is there a way to calculate Accuracy instead of Error metrics for neural networks when doing regression (prediction of continuous variable) the same way we do when classifying categorical variables?

Answer (score 0):

Though, the concept of accuracy comes in the classification, but you can print the predicted values and check them with dependent variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with continuous variable, is that the probability to reproduce exactly a given value is (practically) zero. For instance if your neural network produces 2.000001 and the actual value is 2, then this would count as a wrong prediction as both values are different (although they are very close). Error metric like the root mean square, measure therefore at the average difference (squared).

However, depending on your application, you could introduce a threshold value ϵ and consider a given output of your neural network as correct if the absolute value of the difference between the observed value and the output is smaller than ϵ and compute the percentage of correct prediction.

In practice such a metric is not minimized directly, because it is difficult to compute its gradient, but it is still a useful quantity to compute.